# Why method AbsoluteLayout gets overlined?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set XY position of imageView but method AbsoluteLayout gets overlined like in code below:

```
final ImageView animal = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
animal.setLayoutParams(new <span style="text-AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(animal.getWidth(),animal.getHeight(), x1,y1));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRzjJ.png

Comment: Why do you use absolute layout while it's deprecated already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated, it's not recommended to use it, cause your layout will look different on different devices. Use `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` instead.

Comment: I need Absolute Layout beacouse I have only one imageView on. I need to set coordinates of  that imageView and after that animate it with translate animation.

Comment: @k1c0, you can change your views coordinates in other layouts too, by changing android:layout_margin values

Answer (score 1):

As Egor has mentioned it is already deprecated.

And yes, Whenever you see this kind of overline on any class name or method name or any, it means that it is deprecated class or method or any.

Answer (score 1):

Using an absolute layout is not recommended as others have said (frame layout or relative layout may be better), but if you absolutely must use it, you can use the following bit of code to keep it from tossing warnings right above the offending code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I changed AbsoluteLayout to Relative and now I can use **TranslateAnimation(FromX, ToX, FromY,ToY)**. 
Thanke you guys very much! :)